# Reload list from database or store it as a Parcelable?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have an Activity using a RecyclerView. I set my Adapter in onCreate and pull in the data from an ArrayList of objects.

The kicker: This ArrayList is initially populated through my SQLite database. However, if I rotate the screen, I will have to re-fill that list somehow because the Activity will be destroyed/recreated.

So far I've gotten two methods to work:

1. Re-fill the list by invoking the database again.
2. Re-fill the list by saving it as a Parcelable list through onSaveInstanceState and then restoring it in onCreate by checking if savedInstanceState is null or not. If null, load from database. If not, load from the instance state.

Which of these two methods is the better one and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of these two methods is the better one and why?

IMHO, neither is the right solution.

3. Maintain an LRU, capped-size cache of your model objects built from your database queries, using a singleton cache manager. Store something lightweight, like an `ArrayList` of keys or IDs, in the saved instance state `Bundle`. Use that to retrieve your model objects from the cache, loading them from the database if needed.

The problem with the always-load-from-the-database solution is speed. As noted elsewhere, this takes time, and ideally you don't want to take that kind of time.

The problems with the `Parcelable`-model approach include:

- You have a 1MB limit on the saved instance state `Bundle`, meaning that if the user has a lot of data, this approach crashes (my option #3 above could also crash, but since your keys/IDs will be smaller than the whole model object, it will take far longer to crash)
- `Parcelable` is a pain to maintain, though various libraries exist to help ease that pain via annotations and the like

Comment: `You have a 1MB limit on the saved instance state Bundle` What?! I had no idea. That seems so small. Is there a way I can check the size of the Bundle at runtime to get an idea how close I am to the limit (I'd simulate a heavier load)?

Comment: `Maintain an LRU, capped-size cache of your model objects built from your database queries, using a singleton cache manager` How do I actually maintain something like this without having Android potentially eat it (sometimes it likes to clear things from memory if an app is in the background too long and resources are needed elsewhere)

Comment: @ArukaJ: More generally, there is a 1MB limit on the size of any IPC transaction: starting an activity, starting or binding to a service, sending a broadcast, the saved instance state `Bundle`, etc. "Is there a way I can check the size of the Bundle" -- technically, the limit is not on the `Bundle` itself, but on the size of the `byte[]` representation of all the data in the `Bundle`, which isn't really knowable until after it is all written out to the `byte[]`.

Comment: @ArukaJ: You could create a `Parcel`, call `writeBundle()` on it, passing in your `Bundle`, then call `marshall()` and check the `byte[]` size. Note that there is some overhead elsewhere, so you can't go all the way up to 1MB, though it should be close. "without having Android potentially eat it" -- the only way Android will "eat it" is if Android terminates your process. That's perfectly natural, and it is why this is a *cache*, not the actual persistent data store.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like Parcel parcel = new Parcel();

Comment: I tried Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();, Bundle bundle = new Bundle(), bundle.putParcelableArrayList(TAG, mArrayList); parcel.writeBundle(bundle); byte[] bytes = parcel.marshall(); but not sure how to get size

Comment: @ArukaJ: Call the static `obtain()` method on `Parcel`. Call `recycle()` on the `Parcel` when you are done with it. `length` is how you get the length of any Java array.

Comment: I tried outputting bytes.length to get the size. I get "155" for an ArrayList of one of my (typical in content) object. This implies my list would start to choke around 6000+ objects?

Comment: @ArukaJ: That sounds about right, assuming that your range of object sizes is fairly small. For example, if the user can provide information for these objects, and you support free-form text entry, somebody could paste in something awfully large, causing one object to be a good-sized chunk of the 1MB limit.

Comment: So in theory if I control the max size of the objects as well as the max number of items in the list (e.g. prevent user from making more than x objects), Parcelable would be fine (ignoring the pain of implementing the read/write/CREATOR methods)? I only ask because I have no clue how to write a "LRU, capped-size cache" singleton. Just one big static class with ArrayList members containing objects that I fill/retrieve from, and if it's null in the onCreate method for whatever reason, use the db instead / refill the cache?

Comment: @ArukaJ: "So in theory..." -- the key phrase is "in theory". For an LRU, capped-size cache, see [`LRUCache`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html).

Answer (score 0):

i would day the second way is better. One is that it is much faster to use Parcelables compared to requerying the db. second is that it allows you to modify your data in the list by you or the user and allow it to persist while rotating without having to worry about saving the changes to the database